# What fix should be applied for JTest bug SECURITY.WSC.CACM-1

Tags: java, servlets, jtest

I am working on a project which goes through JTest scan in which one of the bugs is SECURITY.WSC.CACM-1 which states that:

> 'isUserInRole()' is not allowed to be invoked within 'isInRole()',
>   it should only be invoked inside centralized access control method
>   declarations

I have written code as:

```
private HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
            assert (request != null);
            return request;
        }
       @Override
public void onRequestStart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            this.request = request;
        }
public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isInRole("ADMIN");
        }
private boolean isInRole(String role) {
             return getRequest().isUserInRole(role);
        }
```

Where am I wrong . Can anyone give me solution for this?

PS:- Please provide me link if you have for possible fixes for JTest scan defects

Answer (score 0):

This rule says that you shouldn't call access control methods from not specified methods. Your application should have authorization class/module. So your code:

```
private boolean isInRole(String role) {
    return getRequest().isUserInRole(role);
}
```

is incorrect (to check user role) because this method is located in the Servlet. Please move this method to your authorization class and setup this method in your test configuration.